# Excel Bar chart

Tags: windows

Can anyone help me with excel bar chart?
I need to insert that line (i circle it on the picture)

Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3VJe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is Error Bars, which you can access from the Chart > Design ribbon bar.

[image]

Comment: Great thanks for your answer! Really helpful, on point!

Comment: Feel free to mark it as the correct answer, and/or a useful answer @EleniPanayide :)